# PHP Microsoft Graph SDK: How to handle a JSON Batch Response?

Tags: php, json, odata, microsoft-graph-sdks

When performing a Microsoft Graph batch request (partially displayed below), an object response gets returned that contains an array of arrays with all the requested calendar information. However, since the response contains an array of arrays, the SDK function to extract the subject doesn't work. How can I iterate through the arrays within the array in order to use the function? I tried to JSON decode the response, but it expects a string, instead of an object.

Thanks !

Request:

```
$n = count($scheduley, 0);
$request2 = '{ "requests": [';
for ($i = 0; $i < $n;) {
$request2 .= '{ "id": "'.$i.'", "method": "GET", "url": "/users/'.$scheduley[$i]["emailruimte"].'/calendarView?startDateTime='.$today.'T00:00:00.0000000&endDateTime='.$today.'T23:59:59.0000000" },';
$i++;
}
$request2 = rtrim($request2, ',');
$request2 .= ']}';
$event = ($graph
    ->createRequest("POST", "/\$batch")
     ->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
    ->attachBody($request2)
    ->execute());
    $now = Carbon::parse(now()->toDateTimeString())->timezone(
        'Europe/Amsterdam'
    );
    $returnType = new Model\Event;
    $returnedevent = ($event->getResponseAsObject($returnType));
```

Response Object:

```
object(Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event)[19597]
  protected '_propDict' => 
    array (size=1)
      'responses' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => 
            array (size=4)
              'id' => string '2' (length=1)
              'status' => int 200
              'headers' => 
                array (size=2)
                  'Cache-Control' => string 'private' (length=7)
                  'Content-Type' => string 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; IEEE754Compatible=false; charset=utf-8' (length=102)
              'body' => 
                array (size=2)
                  '@odata.context' => string 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('room%40domain.com')/calendarView' (length=100)
                  'value' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => 
                        array (size=41)
                          '@odata.etag' => string 'W/"/etag"' (length=36)
                          'id' => string 'ID' (length=152)
                          'subject' => string 'Subject' (length=5)
```

GetSubject SDK function

```
public function getSubject()
{
    if (array_key_exists("subject", $this->_propDict)) {
        return $this->_propDict["subject"];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was under the assumption that I couldn't iterate over the loop, however I can.

```
$n = count($scheduley, 0);
        $request2 = '{ "requests": [';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n;) {
        $request2 .= '{ "id": "'.$i.'", "method": "GET", "url": "/users/'.$scheduley[$i]["emailruimte"].'/calendarView?startDateTime='.$today.'T00:00:00.0000000&endDateTime='.$today.'T23:59:59.0000000" },';
        $i++;
        }
        $request2 = rtrim($request2, ',');
        $request2 .= ']}';
        $event = ($graph
            ->createRequest("POST", "/\$batch")
             ->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
            ->attachBody($request2)
            ->execute());
            $now = Carbon::parse(now()->toDateTimeString())->timezone(
                'Europe/Amsterdam'
            );
            $whenavailable = [];
            $availability = [];
            $returnType = new Model\Event;
            $eventArray = [];
            $returnedevent = ($event->getResponseAsObject($returnType)->getProperties()['responses']);
            foreach ($returnedevent as $returnedevent){
            $final = $returnedevent['body']['value'];
            //var_dump($final);
            foreach ($final as $final){
                        $eventArray = [
                            'title' => $final['subject'],
                            'room' => $final['organizer']['emailAddress']['address'],
                            'end' => Carbon::parse(
                                $final['end']['dateTime'])->timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'),
                            'start' => Carbon::parse(
                                $final['start']['dateTime'])
                            ->timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
                        ];
```